# Use wildcard in ingress host name

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, wildcard-subdomain, kubernetes-ingress

I want to redirect all *.xxxx.com requests to m-*.xxxx.com using kubernetes. Im using nginx for routing. Is there a way to do this?

Im currently having '*.xxxx.com' in ingress definition,but it doesnt accept something like this : 'm-*.xxxx.com'

Comment: Which Kubernetes version are you using? Always provide these basics please, it's a waste of time to query that in order to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `"*.xxxx.com"` rather than `'*.xxxx.com'`.